# What does "*" operator do before the tensor size in PyTorch?

Tags: python, neural-network, operators, pytorch, tensor

I am now learning building neural networks in PyTorch. Here are the codes cut from the `.py` file:

```
x = torch.unsqueeze(torch.linspace(-1, 1, 1000), dim=1)
y = x.pow(2) + 0.1*torch.normal(torch.zeros(*x.size()))
```

I am quite comfused about the utility of the `*` operator before  `x.size()`. I tried to delete it and plot the scatter graph, which was proved the same as the one with `*` not removed.

I also checked the official documentation of `size` in https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html but I couldn't figure it out.

[Image of torch.size item in documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajFCt.png)

I'd appreciate it very much if you may help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason that * makes no difference in the results here is because `torch.zero` except both **a variable number of arguments** and **a collection like a list or tuple** as mentioned [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.zeros). It does not mean * itself is useless.

Then, since `torch.Size()` class is a subclass of python tuple, one can unpack it using *. (`x.size()` will return a `torch.Size()` object)

So to wrap up, `x.size()` would give you `(1000, 1)` and `*x.size()` *in the argument* would give you `1000, 1` and both are accepted by `torch.zeros()`

Comment: Your answer is very precise and clear! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

`*` used like this in Python denotes (argument) unpacking. When you prepend it to an iterable (which is what `x.size()` returns), it unpacks and (here) passes its items to the function as positional arguments. E.g.:

```
def f(a1, a2):
    print(a1, a2)

f(*["Hello", "World"])
```

You can check out the Docs links for [another example](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=argument%20unpacking#unpacking-argument-lists) and more detailed [description](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists).

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer is easy to follow!